# C# get max resolution on winpe, without any drivers

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, screen-size, winpe

Im looking for a way to get the maximum supported screen resolution.
I need to find this without any drivers installed.
I have already tried using `WMI` and the `EnumDisplaySettings`.

Is it possible to get this information direct from the hardware, or do i need to look it up online? If online, which information do i then need in order to look it up?

Comment: "Without any drivers installed" hardware doesn't work Do you mean standard microsoft drivers will be there? Nice screen name BTW.

Comment: Yes the standard windows drivers will be there, atleast the drivers that come with WinPe will be there. And thnx, i guess.. :)

Answer (score 1):

EnumDisplaySettings give you all the screen resolutions in a loop. It is up to you to choose which one is the "maximum" (the widest or the tallest?)

I've done it, in C++ :

```
for (i=0;; i++) 
{
    memset(&vimodetmp,0,sizeof vimodetmp);
    vimodetmp.dmSize = sizeof vimodetmp;
    if (!EnumDisplaySettings(DisplayDevice.DeviceName,i,&vimodetmp))
    {
        break;
    }
// store in a array
}
// you can choose in the array
```

Hope that can help you.

Comment: Thats what i did but i dosn't show the correct max screen resolution in winpe. I got the max resolution to be 1280x1024 but in reality with drivers installed the computer can run 1400x1050...

Comment: not all resolutions are in the standard drivers. Are you sure that 1400x1050 is in it ? Don't expect having the same behaviour than in "classic" Windows.

Comment: I know that :) With the standard drivers in WinPe I do get the max resolution that is provided be WinPe, and this resolution is 1280x1024. But when I boot into a windows with all drivers installed, the max resolution possible is 1400x1050. What I need to know is how to get this resolution, without drivers installed.

Comment: it's not the max provided by WinPE, it's the max possible for the driver with your screen (for exemple, mine is 1600x1200 in WinPE, wich is not possible in Windows with manufacturer drivers).

Comment: and the answer is : you can't. Mount driver, or take that resolution as max